# Warning C26812: Enum type is unscoped. Prefer enum class over enum

Tags: c++, enums, warnings, sfml

It is puzzling me as to why am I getting this warning at all. I do not even have enumerations in my entire code?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

using sf::RenderWindow;
using sf::VideoMode;
using sf::Event;
using std::vector;
using sf::Vector2f;
using sf::RectangleShape;
using sf::CircleShape;
using sf::Color;
using sf::Keyboard;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(720, 640), "Shooter game w Projectiles.");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    CircleShape player(50.f);
    player.setFillColor(Color::White);
    player.setPosition((window.getSize().x / 2.f) - (player.getRadius()), (window.getSize().y - player.getRadius() * 2) - 10.f);

    CircleShape bullet(5.f);
    bullet.setFillColor(Color::Red);

    vector<CircleShape> playerBullets;
    playerBullets.push_back(bullet);

    RectangleShape enemy(Vector2f(30.f, 30.f));
    enemy.setFillColor(Color::Magenta);
    enemy.setPosition(320, 200);

    vector<RectangleShape> enemies;
    enemies.push_back(enemy);

    enemy.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
    enemy.setPosition(160, 100);
    enemies.push_back(enemy);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }

        // Update
        Vector2f playerCenter = Vector2f(player.getPosition().x + player.getRadius(), player.getPosition().y + player.getRadius());

        // Clear
        window.clear();

        // Draw
        window.draw(player);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < enemies.size(); ++i)
        {
            window.draw(enemies[i]);
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < playerBullets.size(); ++i)
        {
            window.draw(playerBullets[i]);
        }
        

        // Display
        window.display();
    }
}
```

This is the warning that I get: **The enum type 'sf::PrimitiveType' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).** 
It warns me on line number 79, which basically is the new line after the main function closing bracket?

Comment: As it's saying, [`sf::PrimitiveType`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/group__graphics.php#ga5ee56ac1339984909610713096283b1b) is an enumeration. The warning is correct. You can just disable it if you are not interested in this type of warning.

Comment: I have not declared any ```sf::PrimitiveType```. Also, how do I solve this warning. I do not wish to ignore it.

Comment: You included `<SFML/Graphics.hpp>`, which declares it for you. You cannot really "solve" that warning, because that's not your code. You could submit a bug report, but they will not change it because it would break people's code. So the best option is just to disable it.

Comment: Depending on the tools you use, you might be able to mark SFML includes as system includes, so the compiler does not generate warnings for it. For instance with gcc you'd use `-isystem` instead of `-I` when you give the include path for SFML.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do that? Because I have no idea what you just said regarding the ```-isystem```. What even is the difference between SFML includes and system includes? I am a beginner, so I am oblivious to such terms.

Comment: This is tool-specific. The way to do it is different depending on whether you're using gcc, clang, msvc, … So you should tell us what you are using to build, and then hopefully someone who uses the same tool as you can answer :)

Comment: I am using msvc 2019

Comment: [disable warnings from legacy and third party header files](https://blog.bytellect.com/software-development/c-cplusplus/disabling-warnings-from-legacy-and-third-party-header-files/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this warning comes from the header file `SFML\Graphics.hpp` and the only option is to contact the SFML developers and ask them to fix this warning as suggested by @spectras in the comment section. 
 There is no solution that I can implement that will solve the warning. However, it is best to disable all the warnings coming from this third party header file by encapsulating  it within two pragma statements:

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

With thanks to @Thrasher for providing me with the link in the comment section. Here, is the link:
https://blog.bytellect.com/software-development/c-cplusplus/disabling-warnings-from-legacy-and-third-party-header-files/