# Warning C26812: Enum type VkResult is unscoped. Prefer enum class over enum

Tags: visual-studio, enums, visual-studio-2019, warnings

I have found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610623/warning-c26812-enum-type-is-unscoped-prefer-enum-class-over-enum)** question but its solution does not help me.

I include the Vulkan headers as follows:

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

However, I still encounter this warning.
I tried restarting my Visual Studio 2019, however the problem remains.
How do I solve this problem?